# utorrent is not working after reboot in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: utorrent

fter installing utserver 3.3 on ubuntu 16.04, it worked fine and i could download the data. But after restarting the machine and localhost:8080/gui is not working. a blank page is showing on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the service is not running.

Try starting it again with

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ &
```